# URL Parsing Regex

Tags: regex, url

I've made a regex to match some url:

It must match: the protocol (http,https), the username (username@ --if any), the passord(username:password@ --if any), the hostname (either asdf.asdf(etc) or 123.154.213.255) port (:80 -- if any) and **path (starts by a backslash then it follows any combination between / or . or any letter or number)**.

My regex till now:

```
\b(https?)://([a-z]*?@|[a-z]*?:[a-z]*?@)?((([01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.([01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.([01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.([01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]))|([a-z]*\.?)*[a-z])(:[0-9]*)?
```

It's kinda hard to read.
My problem is finding the path.... Till now i have tried (/?) to find the first (possible) / then i tried `(/?/|\.|[a-z]|[0-9]*)` to match any / or . or [a-z0-9] however many times possible, but it's not working.

Comment: Don't forget IPv6 addressess (like `http://[::1]:80/`)

Comment: Im looking only for that specific type of URL I described in my question, not for actual real URLs

Comment: what language do you use?

Comment: C++, but right now I use some only Regex to find the right version of the regex, then Ill port it to c++

Answer (score 0):

I've found the right regex!

It uses a condition that says if I found `/` then i search for `a thru z` and `0 - 9`, `/`, `.` apearing whatever many times.

```
((?(?=/)([a-z0-9]|/|\.)*|))
```